# How to insert a page into a story in ReportLab Python?

Tags: python, reportlab

While compiling a pdf from pages, I'm creating chapter names at the end, on the fly. My biggest problem is that a Story is already compiled by then. So when I do something like this:

```
   for chapter in self.chapters:
             p = Paragraph(chapter,style)
             Story.extend(p)
             Story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))
```

It just doesn't add a page that has the list of chapters at the beginning of the pdf. How do I insert a page then? The Story here already has to content of the book which compiles very well. But I want to add a few additional pages at any point of the pdf. How do I do that?